# Do I need ESD protection on a USB port used for power only?

Tags: power, diodes, usb

If I'm using the supply lines of a USB port only, do I need ESD protection?  Do I use a TVS diode between Vbus and GND or use a USB ESD IC?

Thanks!!

Comment: What kind of USB jack are you using? Mini B, Micro B, USB-C, etc? How much power are you planning to use?

Comment: @mkeith, I have a [Micro B](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/649-10118193-0001LF)

Comment: And you don't use the data lines to sense if the host is a Dedicated Charging Port or anything like that? The data lines are just not connected at all?

Comment: @mkeith, that's more or less the plan.  I've done that on previous projects.  I was thinking about that for this project.  If it's just there for charging, do I need something on the data lines?  But, I don't have an answer for that.

Comment: Just asking. If you literally don't use them, then all you probably need is a capacitor on VBUS to GND. That is kind of what Tony is suggesting in his answer, too, in case you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you applied 3kV from a 100 pF Human Finger Model onto a 100 nF low ESR capacitor, how much attenuation would you expect from this capacitance transformer?

It would matter with ESR ratios,and parasitic inductance, but if we neglect this, we expect a 3V pulse with a time constant of 100 pF * ESR total.   This is unlikely to cause any SOA faults or OVP faults.  (You may look up unfamiliar terms)